# How to stub getTime() method of Date() using sinon?

Tags: unit-testing, sinon

I am using this method but its not working-

```
var date = new Date();    
var getTimeStub = sinon.sandbox.stub(date, 'getTime');
```

Answer (score 0):

To directly answer your question (assuming you still want to use a sandbox):

```
var sandbox = sinon.createSandbox();
var date = new Date();    
var getTimeStub = sandbox.stub(date, 'getTime');
```

Documentation link: http://sinonjs.org/releases/v4.1.2/sandbox/

---

Alternatively (and it really depends on what you're actually doing), you could be using Sinon's *fake timers* to deal with date & time stubbing.

http://sinonjs.org/releases/v4.1.2/fake-timers/

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend you to use fake timers. It's more elegant

```js
// up
const sandbox = sinon.sandbox.create()

// 1 Jan 2017, UTC
const fakeNow = 1483228800 * 1000
sandbox.useFakeTimers(fakeNow)

const now = new Date().getTime()

// down
```